# How do I access both the class and the calling object in an ES2015 class method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is a beginner React.js / ES2015 question.

I have some HTML that displays a list of book names:

```
class BookList extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.books.map((book) =>
                {
                    return (                        
                        <TextField
                            defaultValue={book.name}
                            key={book.name}
                            onEnterKeyDown={this.onBookNameChange}
                            ...
```

And when the user edits a name and presses enter I call a method in my class to check if the book exists and update my store:

```
class BookList extends React.Component
{
    onBookNameChange(event)
    {
        const newBookName = event.target.value;
        if (this.doesBookExistElseShowMessage(newBookName))
            return;
        const oldName = this.defaultValue;
        const oldBooks = Store.getState().books;
        const newBooks = Helper.EditValueInArray(oldBooks, 'name', oldName, newBookName);
        Actions.updateBooks(newBooks);
    }
```

Here's the problem: in this method, how do I access both the *class* (**this.doesBookExistElseShowMessage**) and the *calling object* (**this.defaultValue**) ?

Either **this** is the calling object (the TextField, as it currently is) or I can bind **this** in the class constructor to the class

```
this.onBookNameChange = this.onBookNameChange.bind(this);
```

but then I lose access to the TextField. I can't see any way of getting a reference to both objects in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind it to your instance, and use `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` to access the TextField; this is shown in the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Actually, I think there's a standard React way to hook it up so you don't have to do the bind explicitly (which would be better; binding is cumbersome): When rendering, use `onChange={this.onBookNameChange}`.

Here's the example from the docs:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {value: 'Hello!'};
},
handleChange: function(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
},
render: function() {
  var value = this.state.value;
  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
}
```

Note `handleChange`'s use of `this` and `event.target`.

`target` and `currentTarget` doesn't matter if the handler is bound to an element (like `input type="text"`) that can't contain other elements, but can matter for ones that can: `currentTarget` is the element that you bound the handler to (what you'd see as `this` if you were using `this` for something else). `target` is the element where the event occurred, which can be a descendant element. Think a `div` with a `span` in it: if you've hooked `click` on the `div`, and someone clicks the `span`, `target` will be the `span` and `currentTarget` will be the `div`.

So when replacing `this` with something from `event`, `currentTarget` would be the default thing to reach for to get an equivalent to `this`. `target` is really useful for delegation.

Comment: Actually, better use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, if you want a one-for-one swap for what `this` would have been, good point.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind multiple values to the

```
onEnterKeyDown={this.onBookNameChange}
```

It could look like this

```
onEnterKeyDown={this.onBookNameChange.bind(this, book.name}
```

In your function it would look like this:

```
onBookNameChange(name, ev) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(ev);
  console.log("name: " + name);
}
```